# Ruby Sinatra - Add custom routes for files in Public folders

Tags: ruby, ssh, sinatra, scp

I have a Sinatra app which would be used by different clients. I wish to show the client's Company Logo and a custom layout.erb for each client.

The code base is essentially same for everyone. All I need is a way to easily maintain a different set of files in the 'Public' directory and 'layout.erb', and when deploying to the remote server, automatically copy only the particular client's files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way would be to have a `view` and `public` directory per client and set the proper `:views` and `:public` options for each request

```
get '/:client/...' do
  set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/views/#{params[:client]}"
  set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public/#{params[:client]}"

  # Your code
end
```

Edit based on comment :

Set your public folder during the `config` block.
Now add one subfolder to your public folder for each client. All you have to do to access the specific file is to modify your view to get `/#{params[:client]}/logo.png` instead of `/logo.png`

Comment: Yoann, I wasn't aware of that possibility, thank you! I'd like to however add multiple public folders. A set of files are common to all clients, and only few differ. I'd like to add both to the routes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can set a common public folder, and in it some subfolders with the specific files. Instead of changing the :public options each time you just request the file in the subfolder based on the client

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way solve this problem. It is possible to redefine routes to files in public folders.  In fact, Sinatra first checks whether a 'get' request has a corresponding route, and if it doesn't, it goes to the 'public' folder for static content. So for any client-specific file I need, I use a specifc path like '/client/logo.gif' kind of URL. I created a route for such files and applied my custom logic there:

```
get '/client/logo.gif' do
  #custom logic..
  redirect "#{where_client_files_are}/logo.gif"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code to your *ruby/sinatra* file

example : create images. style and scripts directory under your project and below code

```
get '/project1/images/:file' do
  send_file('/home/sulo/dev/project1/images/'+params[:file], :disposition => 'inline')
end

get '/project1/style/:file' do
  send_file('/home/sulo/dev/project1/style/'+params[:file], :disposition => 'inline')
end

get '/project1/scripts/:file' do
  send_file('/home/sulo/dev/project1/scripts/'+params[:file], :disposition => 'inline')
end
```